# Listing duplicate emails in Excel mailing lists

Tags: excel

Im trying to create a list of values in 'sheet 3 column A', that are created by listing all values that are duplicates in two other sheets.

The duplicates are to be found by looking through each value in 'sheet 1 column P'  and checking if that value also exists in 
'sheet 2  column A'

I've tried reading up on this and there seem to be a number of functions I can use and not sure if I should use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the VLOOKUP function, combined with IF. Together they are very very powerful. I really suggest you read up on them.

The following formula in Sheet 3, Column A (starting at row 2) will do what you want:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!P2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$99,1,FALSE)),"",Sheet1!P2)
```

Copy that formula down from A2. I've assumed you have headings in row A. If you have more than 98 rows of emails (values to check), change $A$99 to be something like $A$9999.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Im reading up on VLOOKUP and IF and ISNA. At the moment Column A - Sheet3 is not recognising either a function or one of the ranges - it is saying #NAME? I can't see any problems wit your formula so not sure why this is happening

Comment: Are the worksheets called "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3" etc? This is definitely not beginners Excel. Double check everything :)

Comment: Im actually using Libre Office Cals Spread sheet so I changed it to =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1.P2,sheet2.$a$2.$a$9999,1,0)),"",Sheet1.P2) an it worked - thanks so much

Comment: it listed everyone in Sheet1 P2

Answer (score 0):

This can be refined slightly using `iferror` giving:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!P2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$99,1,False),"",Sheet1!P2)
```

but is essentially the same thing

Answer (score 0):

So, let me get this straight. You have two workbook tabs. You want to get the intersection of the set (figure out where they are overlapping, duplicate, however you want to say it).

I would do one of two things, depending on how much you like Excel and moving your data around.

**Option 1: Create a PivotTable of the data (assumes no duplicates within lists, only between lists)**

- Copy the data from the second list after the end of the first list (so both lists are now one list)
- Insert a Pivot Table (on the ribbon), choosing your single column for the source
- PivotTable options will pop up. Put the email address field in RowLabels and Count in the Summarize Values box.
- Click on the count column of the pivot and sort largest to smallest.
- All your duplicates will have Count > 1

**Option 2 - use CountIf**

- This does not involve moving your data.
- Go to sheet 2. In the next column over (from your info, it would be Column Q), put the CountIf function:
  `=CountIf(Sheet1!A:A,P2)`
- Then you can sort descending on your new count column to find duplicates.
- CountIf performs very well in Excel if your lists are very large.